# How to get the duration or total number of frame in ffmpeg filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm writing a filter in ffmpeg in which I have to get the duration of the video. The filter_frame function  looks like followings:

```
static int filter_frame(AVFilterLink* link, AVFrame* in) {
    AVFilterContext* avctx = link->dst;
    ExtractContext* privCtx = (ExtractContext*)avctx->priv;
    AVFilterLink* outlink = avctx->outputs[0];
    //here I want to get the duration or total number of frames:
}
```

I have to get the duration or total number of frames in this function, but the only parameters of the function is AVFilterLink and AVFrame in which I cant find relative fields, so I dont know how to do.
Can you help me? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: That info is not exported.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I found that the duration can be fetched from the 'duration' field of  AVFormatContext class. However the parameter of filter_frame is AVFilterLink and AVFrame. It looks like that there is no way to get AVFormatContext using AVFilterLink and AVFrame.

Comment: Indeed. I suggest that before sending frames to buffersrc, add a avdictionary string entry to the avframe with the value.

Comment: Thanks for your advice！AVFrame exactly have a AVDictionary called 'metadata'. I have searched some usage of AVDictionary. But I have just learned how to add a self-written filter to ffmpeg and I don't know where I can modified the 'metadata' field before sending frames to buffersec. Can I ask for your advice about  where (or in which function or process )  I can add the string entry into AVFrame?

Comment: After avformat_open_input returns, the avstream->nb_frames and duration should be populated. Save those values. During decoding, once you have a frame, use av_dict_set to add it to the avframe.

Comment: Thanks very much！I will try it now! :)